# How to use the validation rule :unique on a data by comparing only a foreign_key

Tags: php, laravel

I have a `types` table with these columns :

- id
- name
- team_id

I would like to make the `name` field unique. That is to say that if I add the type "Big", I could'nt add the type "Big" again.

I tried this :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required|min:2|unique:types,name'
    ]);

    ...
}
```

If I do that, it works. But if another team adds a type that already exists in database, it tells me that the type already exists.

What I would like to do is make the type unique only for everyone data who has the same `team_id`

It's possible ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required|min:2|unique:name'.$request->team_id
    ]);


    ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry @Hammadr097, it's exactly what I did It does not count team_id

Comment: I have amended my answer, kindly try again.

Answer (score 0):

primary key can't be repeated so you can't check that two team would have same team_id.

Answer (score 0):

why not use if condition. if name not unique, check if team_id unique or not

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#using-closures

```
$this->validate($request, [
   `name` => [
                 `required`,
                 `min:2`,
                 function($attribute, $value, $fail) {

                    /* your query here for check name unique or not */                     

                    return $fail($attribute.` is invalid.`);
                 },
             ]
]);
```

Or Use Like This.

```
Rule::unique('types')->ignore($user->id),
```

Hope This Helps. :)